# How to Access Global Variable in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to use variable which is set in one file and want to access variable in another file. How to do it in Robot framework.

Currently my file test_1.robot has variable

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections 

*** Test Cases ***
Getting a valid response
    Create Http Session    rest_session    ${service_url}
    Set Global Variable   ${HEADERS}
```

Now I want to access `${HEADERS}` in another file test_2.robot. In test_2.robot I am trying to print headers to console. But i get no such variable `${HEADERS}`.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections 

*** Test Cases ***
Getting a valid response
    Create Http Session    rest_session    ${service_url}
    Log to console  ${HEADERS}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Syntax for setting global variable is the following: `Set Global Variable    ${VARIABLE_NAME}    VALUE`

Comment: yes I am doing it correctly in parent file (test_1.robot) the variable is printing fine. However it is not getting accessed in test_2.robot.

Comment: In example you provided you are not doing, you have only `Set Global Variable ${HEADERS}`

Comment: its an example code. On my local machine I tried printing it. Here I have not shared complete code.

Comment: Please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In your example `${HEADERS}` variable is empty you need to assign it to something and create the variable in `*** Variables ***` section of your file if you want to use in a different file.

This is a simple way to use Global Variables

You can Either use `Set Global Variable`:

> Makes a variable available globally in all tests and suites.
>
> Variables set with this keyword are globally available in all test
>   cases and suites executed after setting them. Setting variables with
>   this keyword thus has the same effect as creating from the command
>   line using the options --variable or --variablefile. Because this
>   keyword can change variables everywhere, it should be used with care.

```
Set Global Variable    ${Header}    ${xpath_to_header}
```

Or you can use `Set Suite Variable`:

> Makes a variable available everywhere within the scope of the current
>   suite.
>
> Variables set with this keyword are available everywhere within the
>   scope of the currently executed test suite. Setting variables with
>   this keyword thus has the same effect as creating them using the
>   Variable table in the test data file or importing them from variable
>   files.
>
> Possible child test suites do not see variables set with this keyword
>   by default. Starting from Robot Framework 2.9, that can be controlled
>   by using children= as the last argument. If the specified
>    is a non-empty string or any other value considered true in
>   Python, the variable is set also to the child suites. Parent and
>   sibling suites will never see variables set with this keyword.
>
> The name of the variable can be given either as a normal variable name
>   (e.g. ${NAME}) or in escaped format as \${NAME} or $NAME. Variable
>   value can be given using the same syntax as when variables are created
>   in the Variable table.
>
> If a variable already exists within the new scope, its value will be
>   overwritten. Otherwise a new variable is created. If a variable
>   already exists within the current scope, the value can be left empty
>   and the variable within the new scope gets the value within the
>   current scope.

```
Set Suite Variable     ${Header}    ${xpath_to_header}
```

Now you can use your `${Header}` variable in your test case. Now you can log the variable as follows

```
log  ${Header}
```

Full example:

```
*** Settings ***


*** Keywords ***
Random Global Variable
    ${Header}=   Set Variable  xpath=//div...
    set suite variable    ${Header}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    log to console   ${Header}
```